# How to edit a "PHP-MySQL-returned" HTML table and update it on the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a simple PHP code to retrieve data from MySQL database table. After this HTML table is displayed, I want to edit certain fields so that they are updated on the database.

Please tell me as to what and how to do.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `<form>` instead of table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the retrieved data go into form fields like this:

```
<input type='text' name='age' value='<?php echo $age; ?>'>
```

This way, the form is pre-filled with the listing data. Also, on the page the form goes to, have that data (which comes to it via $_POST) written back into the database.

Comment: you forgot htmlspecialchars

Comment: Try tizag.com (http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forms.php) - it's a great site for learning PHP basics with simple examples that break lots of things down to very simple steps.

Comment: I agree with @ScottCarmichael, don't rely on w3schools.^_^